# what parameter can be used in URL to switch off subtitles in youtube video

Tags: youtube

I have a video which I need to upload on a company's website but that video has subtitles, which we do not want to show in the website, is there anyway or any parameter defined which we can add in YouTube URL and the subtitle doesn't play.

Kindly suggest.

Thanks and Regards,
Shashank Agarwal